# What is throwing the 'NSValidationErrorValue' error in Core Data when trying to save entities with relationships in my Swift/SwiftUI iOS app?

Tags: swift, core-data

may I preface this by saying I am self taught and this is my first project with Swift and CoreData, so there may be many little errors in my code.
I am trying to develop an app for personal use where I can save ingredients (this works) and I can create `Meals` which contain these `Ingredients`. These entities are connected with a relationship many-to-many. However, when I try saving a meal with some ingredients in it, it throws an error from the `saveContext` function. If I print the Meal I am trying to save it does indeed contain the correct Ingredients. Code and error following, let me know if other snippets are needed.
Thanks for the help! :)

I am using Swift 5, XCode 14.3.

This is my code:

```
    private func saveAction(){
        withAnimation {
            if selectedMeal == nil{
                selectedMeal = MealItem(context: viewContext)
            }
            selectedMeal?.name = name
            selectedMeal?.notes = notes
            for i in ingredients{
                if let meal = selectedMeal{
                    i.addToIsin(meal)
                }
               // selectedMeal?.addToHas(i)
            }
            mealHolder.saveContext(viewContext)
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

```
class MealHolder: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var mealItems: [MealItem] = []
    
    init(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext)
    {
        refreshMealItems(context)
    }
    
    func refreshMealItems(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext)
    {
        mealItems = fetchMealItems(context)
    }
    
    func fetchMealItems(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [MealItem]
    {
        do
        {
            return try context.fetch(MealFetch()) as [MealItem]
        }
        catch let error
        {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func MealFetch() -> NSFetchRequest<MealItem>
    {
        let request = MealItem.fetchRequest()
        
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
   
    func saveContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        do {
            try context.save()
            refreshMealItems(context)
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
@objc(MealItem)
public class MealItem: NSManagedObject {
    
    var ingredients: [IngredientItem]?{
        return self.has?.allObjects as? [IngredientItem]
    }
        
    convenience init(name: String, passedIngredients: [IngredientItem], notes: String? = "", nosave: Bool = false) {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
        let context = persistenceController.container.viewContext
        
        if nosave {
            self.init(entity: MealItem.entity(), insertInto: nil)
        } else {
            self.init(entity: MealItem.entity(), insertInto: context)
        }
        
        var carbs: Float = 0
        var proteins: Float = 0
        var fats: Float = 0
        
        for i in passedIngredients{
            carbs += i.carbs
            proteins += i.proteins
            fats += i.fats
            
            self.addToHas(i)
        }
        
        self.name = name
        self.carbs = carbs
        self.proteins = proteins
        self.fats = fats
        self.notes = notes
        self.carbsblocks = carbs/9
        self.proteinsblocks = proteins/7
        self.fatsblocks = fats/3
        self.blocks = (self.carbsblocks + self.proteinsblocks + self.fatsblocks)/3
    } 
}
```

```
extension MealItem {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MealItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MealItem>(entityName: "MealItem")
    }

    @NSManaged public var blocks: Float
    @NSManaged public var carbs: Float
    @NSManaged public var fats: Float
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var notes: String?
    @NSManaged public var proteins: Float
    @NSManaged public var carbsblocks: Float
    @NSManaged public var proteinsblocks: Float
    @NSManaged public var fatsblocks: Float
    @NSManaged public var has: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for has
extension MealItem {

    @objc(addHasObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToHas(_ value: IngredientItem)

    @objc(removeHasObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromHas(_ value: IngredientItem)

    @objc(addHas:)
    @NSManaged public func addToHas(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeHas:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromHas(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension MealItem : Identifiable {
}
```

And this is the meal+error printed in console:

```
"NSValidationErrorObject": <MealItem: 0x282754b40> (entity: MealItem; id: 0x28040e800 <x-coredata:///MealItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD13>; data: {
    blocks = "9.046561";
    carbs = "0.1";
    carbsblocks = "0.01111111";
    fats = 81;
    fatsblocks = 27;
    has =     (
        "0x28044f760 <x-coredata:///IngredientItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD3>"
    );
    name = "";
    notes = "";
    proteins = "0.9";
    proteinsblocks = "0.1285714";
}), "NSValidationErrorValue": Relationship 'has' on managed object (0x282754b40) <MealItem: 0x282754b40> (entity: MealItem; id: 0x28040e800 <x-coredata:///MealItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD13>; data: {
    blocks = "9.046561";
    carbs = "0.1";
    carbsblocks = "0.01111111";
    fats = 81;
    fatsblocks = 27;
    has =     (
        "0x28044f760 <x-coredata:///IngredientItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD3>"
    );
    name = "";
    notes = "";
    proteins = "0.9";
    proteinsblocks = "0.1285714";
}) with objects {(
    <IngredientItem: 0x2827699a0> (entity: IngredientItem; id: 0x28044f760 <x-coredata:///IngredientItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD3>; data: {
    carbs = "0.1";
    fats = 81;
    isin =     (
        "0x28040e800 <x-coredata:///MealItem/t438A2E60-31AA-4F12-9C16-8D563DA092DD13>"
    );
    name = Burro;
    notes = "";
    proteins = "0.9";
    quantity = 100;
    unit = g;
})
```

Comment: Try without the `for` loop. You should be able to say `selectedMeal?.has = Set(ingredients)`. Core data will take care of the inverse relationship for you.  Have you set any validation rules on your core data entities?

Comment: It throws the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Set<IngredientItem>' to type 'NSSet'", and by assigning `selectedMeal?.has = NSSet(ingredients` it throws "Missing argument label 'object:' in call". I'm sorry, what do you mean with validation rules? I don't think I did though.

Comment: Since you have generated swift files for your entities I would recommend changing from NSSet to Set for the relationship properties, `@NSManaged public var has: Set<IngredientItem>` for clearer code and to get some help from the compiler. (You also need to update `has` and `isin` accessors that uses NSSet)

Comment: Hmm a Swift set should be toll-free bridged to NSSet. Have you set your relationships correctly in your core data model?

Comment: Changing from `NSSet` to `Set` gives me a number of errors and problems with NS stuff that honestly I have not the skills to solve, I'm sorry. 

My relationships in the model are: MealItem `has` IngredientItem, inverse `isin`, optional, Delete rule: nullify, type: To Many, not ordered, unbounded. Same settings for `isin`.